# PayPal IPN looping through cart items in PHP, String literal problem

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to create an array containing all of the purchased items from a PayPal cart purchase. To me, something like this should work (writing to a test file), but it doesn't:

```
$test = fopen('test.txt', 'w');

$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$cart = []; 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) { 
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name' . $i]; 
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number' . $i]; 
    $item_price = $_POST['mc_gross_' . $i]; 
    $item_details = [$item_name, $item_number, $item_price];
    $cart[] = $item_details;
} 

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($test, "$key => $value \r\n");
} 
fwrite($test, $cart);
fclose($test);
```

All of the key/value pairs from the `$_POST` print nicely, but am I doing something wrong with the `for` loop ... I've seen multiple examples online using similar concatenations, but I'm having no luck. After the keys/values are printed, my `$cart` is simply blank (nothing written to the file). It's probably something obvious...

Comment: well `$cart` is an array, have you tried:  `fwrite($test, json_encode($cart));`for example?

Comment: Ah so simple...yep that did it. Thanks -- is that always required when e.g. writing arrays to a document??

Comment: Well you can see from here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php that frwite requires as second argument a string